# find and replace text in a perl script

Tags: perl

so I know that there are many ways of doing what I am asking for, but all that I have found is not helping me for what I am trying to do.
It is supposed to be a simple find and replace script using stdin and stdout.
I have a script called replace.pl and this is what i have in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<STDIN>){
  $_ = s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/g;
  print STDOUT $_;
}
```

When I run `echo "replace a with b please" | replace.pl 'a' 'b'`
all I get back is a "1". My desire output is "replace b with b please" but what ever I try to do, it is not changing it. Could any one tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/g;
```

instead of

```
$_ = s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/g;
```

as `s///` returns 1 when substitution was successful.

You can also quote search pattern if it should be literal string (not a regex),

```
  s/\Q$ARGV[0]\E/$ARGV[1]/g;
```

Comment: oh my gosh... lol thanks. I almost freaking had it. I cant believe i missed that. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer):

> - **s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer**
>
>   Searches a string for a pattern, and if found, replaces that pattern with the replacement text and **returns the number of substitutions made.**  Otherwise it returns false (specifically, the empty string).

That's why the code sets `$_ = 1`.  You just want to do `s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/g;` for its substitution side-effect, without assigning its return value to `$_`.

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/g;
    print;
}
```